# Migrating to v2 - Setting up Linked Services - ODBC Cisco Information Server

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to duplicate the services from Data Factory v1 to Data Factory v2.  I have a working linked service in Data Factory v1.  I set up a new Runtime Integration in v2 and tried to create a new ODBC linked service with the following connection string:

"DRIVER={Cisco Information Server 7.0};HOST=an.example.com;PORT=9401; DOMAIN=US;DATASOURCE=company;"

I get the following Error: Connection failed
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

It works in DFv1, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. The Cisco Information Server 7.0 ODBC driver was not installed on the computer hosting the Runtime Integration.